# Select Box Validation In angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to enable the save button on successfully validation:

```
<form name="schedulerForm" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" ng-class="{'has-error' : schedulerForm.jobName.$invalid && !schedulerForm.jobName.$pristine }">
                    <h4 class="text-center">Assign Job Schedule</h4>                    
                        <select class="form-control" ng-change="getJobDetail(filterType)"
                            ng-model="filterType" id="jobName" required name="jobName">
                            <option value="">Select Job</option>
                            <option value="{{job.id}}" ng-selected="filterType == job.id"
                                ng-repeat="job in jobs" ng-disabled="jobStatus">{{job.jobName}}</option>
                        </select>                   
                </div>
            </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
                                ng-click="assignSchedule()" ng-disabled="schedulerForm.$invalid">Save</button>
</form>
```

On successfull validation I am unable to get the enable button its always in disabled mode..
Please help me out or guide where I am doing mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have created a plunker with your html, its working as is.

just select any value from the list, the button gets enabled.

[PLUNKER LINK](http://embed.plnkr.co/BExoFqNMj1Op1lBDcBH4/preview)